# Metric space in $\mathbb{R}$ with discrete metric. Is a point always closed?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm working on this problem. We are in a metric space (X,d) with X = $\mathbb{R}$ and d := discrete. 
I define the ball with center p and radius 1 as:
$$B_d= \{x \in \mathbb{R} : d(x,p) < 1 \}$$ I understand that the only point satisfying this condition with the discrete metric is p itself, so I have:
$$B_d(p,1) = \{p\}$$
Now I need to find the closure of $B_d(p,1)$. I tried to use this definition: The closure of a set  is the intersection of all the the closed set containing A. However, I could not find the solution.

Comment: Metric spaces are T1.

Comment: Each point in this metric is insulated.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space, the discreteness is irrelevant. Fix $x\in X$, then for all $y\neq x$, let $U_y=\{u\in X\mid d(y,u)<d(y,x)\}$. Namely, if $r=d(x,y)$, then $U_y=B_r(y)$.

It is easy to check that $x\notin U_y$ and $y\in U_y$ for all $y$, and therefore $\bigcup_{x\neq y}U_y$ is an open set. But this is exactly $X\setminus\{x\}$.

Comment: If I understood correctly this means that the closure of $B_d(p,1)$ is just the point p?

Comment: Yes. Assuming that you mean that the discrete metric is $d(x,y)=1$ for all $x\neq y$, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Show that in a discrete metric space, *every* subset is open and therefore *every* subset is closed.  Hint: singletons are open as you have shown, and an arbitrary union of open sets is open.

Thus (using Asaf's solution as well) the desired statement admits two strong generalizations:  In every metric space, singletons are closed.  And in a discrete metric space, every set is closed.

**Extra credit:**  Show that Cauchy sequences are eventually constant. What does that tell you?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for any $T_1$ topological space, any singleton is closed. The metric topology induced by the metric is of course $T_1$ (and actually a lot more...).